# matlab optimization toolbox - polynomial fitting

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, curve, polynomials

I have a set of x and y values that I would like to fit a polynomial curve around. The function should take the form of up to a 9th order polynomial;

```html
y = a(1)*X.^1 + a(2)*X.^2 + a(3)*X.^3 + a(4)*X.^4 + a(5)*X.^5 + a(6)*X.^6 + a(7)*X.^7 + a(8)*X.^8 + a(9)*X.^9;
```

where a(n) are my coefficients.

There are two issues I have. This curve might not always take the form of a 9th order polynomial. It may be a 3rd order, 6th order or whatever (UP TO max 9th order).

I am unsure how to set this up using the optimisation toolbox. Any ideas?

Secondly, can I set a constraint so that the calculated y values are always postive?

Many thanks,

Current code below.

Function;

```html
function F = polyfun(a,redCO2)
F = a(1)*redCO2.^1 + a(2)*redCO2.^2 + a(3)*redCO2.^3 + a(4)*redCO2.^4 + a(5)*redCO2.^5 + a(6)*redCO2.^6 + a(7)*redCO2.^7 + a(8)*redCO2.^8 + a(9)*redCO2.^9;
```

```html
F = @(a) polyfun(a,X);

a0 = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]; % Starting guess

a = lsqcurvefit(@polyfun,a0,X,y);
```

Comment: Apologies, function code should read X where it says redCO2

Comment: If you have access to it, the curve fitting toolbox would probably be a better tool to use for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate requests.

For the unconstrained fit, you don't need any function at all, the problem is linear and `mrdivide` and/or `pinv` gives the best fit in the least-squares sense:

```
a = y / bsxfun(@power, x, 1:9);
```

or

```
a = y * pinv(bsxfun(@power, x, 1:9));
```

If the system is underconstrained, one of these will give a "small" solution in the l2-norm sense, the other in the l0-norm sense.  If the system is fully or over constrained, they'll both give the value of `a` that minimizes the integral-square error (l2-norm).

For a constrained fit, the `lsqcurvefit` function you've already discovered works well.  Just set the `lb` argument to a vector of zeros to force `a` to be non-neqgative:

```
a = lsqcurvefit(@polyval,a0,X,y,zeros(1,9));
```

Comment: Ah great thanks - this solves my second issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html), that's precisely what it's designed for:

```
% Data you want to fit in x and y
% n is the polynomial order of your choosing
% the polynomial coefficients are returned in the vector p
p = polyfit(x,y,n);
```

You can then use `polyval` to evaluate the polynomial `p` over a vector of `x` values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I do not know what "n" is though in each case. Hence why I want to use the optimisation toolbox.

Comment: How do you expect to find the polynomial coefficients if you don't know the degree? You can try various ones and use the `[p,S] = polyfit(x,y,n)` syntax, which also returns a structure `S` that will tell you more info about the goodness of fit. Check the doc.

Comment: @user3491279: Use `n=9`, the max order.  If a lower order polynomial is better, you can get zeros in the answer.